# Running ZFS as MediaStorage with non ECC-Ram

Tags: linux, hard-drive, unix, raid, zfs

First to the Setup:
I'm planning to use 8-11 USB3 Disks to form a MediaStorage
The idea is to use 2 USB3 Hubs to balance the load between two seperate USB3 Ports (on different hubs)

Now from what I've read so far it seems a terrible idea to use any kind of software Raid when you only got non-ECC RAM
https://pthree.org/2013/12/10/zfs-administration-appendix-c-why-you-should-use-ecc-ram/

Studys from google say you get bitflipping approximatly 8% per DIMM per year, with 4 DIMMs its just 32% that you got one bitflip per year if the server is running 24/7

Since I only store big media files where i don't care if i loose a bit or byte a year, and any degredation of this kind seems not to pose a serious threat

Since i already got 16GB of ram and I don't want to buy new ones the quesion is, is the threat so great or is there a better alternative to ZFS ? Raid6 would be nice =)

Answer (score 1):

If, as you said, you're not too worried about a potentially small failure rate then give ZFS with non-ECC a try. Set up the pool(s) with some form of redundancy (copies=2, raidz or raidz2) and check their integrity regularly with `zpool scrub`. Any bit errors will be picked up during the scrub and should be automatically repaired if the pool has some form of redundancy.

I use ECC memory and back up to external USB HDDs with ZFS. I have on one occasion detected an error on the backup during a scrub so, even with ECC, the process is not error-free. Bit errors can occur at the disk level, during read/write or the media itself.

Using ECC helps prevent bit errors while the data is in RAM. ZFS checksums and redundant pools help prevent bit errors on disk.

Comment: Thought it would be wise to use at least raidz2.